# Copy Text from one browser window to another programmatically

Tags: javascript, c#, html, copy-paste

I have this two browser windows, which are opened for each order on an apparel list with about 18K orders. I have to manually copy the values from the first window and paste them on the corresponding inputs in the second window. This has to be repeated for every single order.

I was thinking about making a small tool which allows to identify both windows, copy the needed values and paste them on the second window. Is this possible with Javascript & HTML, or maybe C#?

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1):

Technically, this cannot be achieved via JavaScript. You can use some automation tools like AutoIt e.g.

Some Keyboards are also supporting Marco functions. You can record a Macro and copy every record if the entire process is repeatable.

Comment: AutoIT sounds good, I'll check it right now. My keyboard does have macro keys, but I'm afraid they have a limit of characters. This task may require a lot of them.

Answer (score 0):

I think, this could be achieved with a chrome extension.

In general, the chrome extension needs to do the following

- query all the input fields on the left window and store its values in a JS object.
- use Window.postMessage() API or something similar to send the JS object to the other window where you listen to the message and receive the content (Tricky part is to define who is sender and who is receiver).
- Then you set the value of the input fields to the values of the received js object.

Answer (score 0):

first, in which platform, windows or other os，
and two browser windows are desktop applications or web browser,
if it is web browser, you can try selenium or playwright, can attach the browser window and scraping the data from window 1 and filled in window 2.

if it is desktop application or mixed with web browser, and if you familiar with python, you can try the following visual studio extension clicknium, it can do automation on both web and desktop applation, support recorde the ui elements.

then it is easy way to do data coping from one application to another application.
the following is the sample code:

```
import subprocess
from time import sleep
from clicknium import clicknium as cc, locator, ui

def main():
    # sample code to demo web automation and desktop application
    tab = cc.edge.open("https://www.bing.com/")
    tab.find_element(
        locator.new_store.sample.bing.search_sb_form_q).set_text('clicknium')
    tab.find_element(locator.new_store.sample.bing.svg).click()
    sleep(3)
    tab.close()

    process = subprocess.Popen("notepad")
    ui(locator.new_store.sample.notepad.document_15).set_text("clicknium")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```